# Share class instance between two clients (python)

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm building a very simple multiplayer web game. It's tron lightcycles, but to turn, the user must solve an arithmetic problem.

I've been working on a particular problem for 2-3 days because I didn't fully understand what was going on. Every time a game started, I would create an instance of a class called Flux in which to store game data. The problem was, since there are two players, two instances of Flux are created.

I need only one, and I need to be able to share this instance with the opposing player. How?

I'm using django 1.11.17, django-channels 1.x, python 3.6

I looked at this answer: [Issue with setting value for Python class inherited from multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569175/issue-with-setting-value-for-python-class-inherited-from-multiprocessing-process/16570147#16570147)

Is the multiprocessing module a good fit for my case?

Answer (score 0):

no due to how channels runtime works there is no garenty multiprocessing will work.

what i suggest you do instread is:

1. upgrade to channels v2
2. create a db model that will hold your game state
3. whenver a player does an action update the model and send a message over the channel group to the other player so that new state can be sent to the user.

for this last step you could make use of https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework this post gives some more deatils with respect to model deatils https://lostmoa.com/blog/DjangoChannelsRestFrameworkSubscribingToModels/

Comment: I update game state every 100ms. That's too many database queries

Comment: what about writing that to redis instead of a db model?

Comment: I thought tried that. But I'd have to initialize a redis instance every time the game state changes. Initializing a redis instance takes anywhere from 2-6 seconds, which is way too long.

Comment: you should be able to keep a single instance active and have a single connection to it.

Comment: Where? The function, ws_receive, executes only when data is sent to it (through websocket). If I define it outside the ws_receive, ws_receive never sees it. If I put it inside the function, the instance is only defined for that window of time in which the ws_receive code is executed, for that _one_ period.

Comment: just create a connection to redis when the server start up. And re-use that connection for all operations from that server thread.

Since you just need to `write` values with redis (you can use the channel layer to inform the other connections of the change) it should be quite simple to use a global connection.